# Exclude specific notification channel in particural moment

Tags: c#

Below solution which is responsible for diffrent ways of notifications like logging into file, sending emails, print to the console. My problem is when i register channels i am not able then to exclude one of them just for particural moment. At the bottom of my code you will see the problem i have couple operations and only for operation nr 3 i would like for a moment to exclude mailnotificator then on operation nr 4 i want to enable it again. Can you help me out how in correct way to change my code to do it?

```
public interface INotificationChannel
    {
        Task Send(Message message);
    }

    public interface INotificationChannelEngine
    {
        void Process(Message message);
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string Text;
    }


    public class MailNotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
    {
        public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            //to be implemented
        }
    }

    public class FileNotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
    {
        public string Path = Common.Log;
        public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            Logger.LogIt(message.Text, Path);
            await Task.Delay(0);
        }
    }

    public class ConsoleNotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
    {
        public string Path;
        public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Text);
            await Task.Delay(0);
        }
    }

//other notification channels..

    public class NotificationChannelEngine : INotificationChannelEngine
    {
        private readonly IList<INotificationChannel> _notificationChannels;
        public NotificationChannelEngine()
        {
            _notificationChannels = new List<INotificationChannel>();
        }

        public void RegisterNotificationChannel(INotificationChannel channel)
        {
            _notificationChannels.Add(channel);
        }

        public void Send(Message message)
        {
            foreach (var channel in _notificationChannels)
                channel.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Entry point where i register channels, passing notification channels into constructor of specific class Runner:

```
public class Program
{
        private static readonly NotificationChannelEngine NotificationChannel = new NotificationChannelEngine();

        public static void Main()
        {
            //shared variables
            Common.Log = new Database().GetLogPath();
            Common.IsDebug = new Database().GetisDebug();
            //registering specific channels
            NotificationChannel.RegisterNotificationChannel(new FileNotificationChannel() { Path = "mypath" });
            NotificationChannel.RegisterNotificationChannel(new ConsoleNotificationChannel());
            NotificationChannel.RegisterNotificationChannel(new ConsoleNotificationChannel());

            new Runner(NotificationChannel).Run(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Wait();
        }
    }

Now in class runner i do some notifications, for instance only for operation nr 3 i would like to exclude mail notification channel, just for this one.

     internal class Runner
        {
             public INotificationChannelEngine NotificationChannelEngine;

             public Runner(INotificationChannelEngine notificationengine)
             {
                    NotificationChannelEngine = notificationengine;
             }

             public async Task Run(DateTime date)
             {
                 try
                 {
                 //some operation 1
                 NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log"});

                //some operation 2
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log 2"});

                //some operation 3
                //i would like exclude mail from here
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log 2"});

    //now resume mail again
                //some operation 4
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log 2"});

                 } 
            }    
        }


     public sealed class Logger
{
    private static readonly Mutex Locker = new Mutex(false, $"Global\{new Guid()}");
    public Logger()
    {
    }

    public static void Log(string msg, string filePath)
    {
        Locker.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            var message = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")} > {msg}";
            if (ApplciationConfig.DeveloperMode)
            {
                var fileNameWithoutPath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                var dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                filePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileNameWithoutPath + "_debug" + fileExtension);
            }

            using (TextWriter w = File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                w.WriteLine(message);
                w.Flush();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Locker.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

First of all i wanted to add a parameter to Process, or a static on NotificationChannelEngine that i could set like

NotificationChannelEngine.Suppress(mail??) and NotificationChannelEngine.Resume(mail??)

However then i thought my Runner class would know about one of the channels are email and to me that's not right because Runner should knows nothing about specific channels but only that there are some channels according to OOP if i am not mistaken.

Could you review my code and propose possible solution? If anything unclear let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option with minimal refactoring would be to create a `EventType/MessageType/NotificationType` enum that lists all the different types of events that trigger notifications to be sent. Once you have that, adjust your notification channel registration mechanism to allow channels to register either for global events (everything) or only for a specific set of event types that they care about (bitmasking or a collection would work). You can then adjust your `Message` object to have a new `EventType` field which your `NotificationEngine.Process` method can consume in order to determine which channels should actually be notified with that message as long as you've updated your `_notificationChannels` data structure to allow you to filter the channels based on the types of messages they each want to subscribe to. You can use that enum to discriminate between channels instead of requiring top-down knowledge of channels and supressing/reenabling them. That way you maintain separation of concerns because your channels are the entities that know what they care about and the notification engine only knows how to filter and send messages to channels and the message generators know what kinds of messages they are creating but no entity has to know how any other piece of the system works.

This is basically a [publisher/subscriber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern.

Edit: Here's a modified version of your sample code to point you in the right direction. Untested but compiling.

```
    public interface INotificationChannel
    {
        Task Send(Message message);
    }

    public interface INotificationChannelEngine
    {
        void RegisterNotificationChannel(INotificationChannel channel, MessageType messageType);
        void Process(Message message);
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public MessageType MessageType;
        public string Text;
    }


    public class MailNotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
    {
        public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            //to be implemented
        }
    }

    public class FileNotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
    {
        public string Path = "Some filepath";
        public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            Logger.Log(message.Text, Path);
            await Task.Delay(0);
        }
    }

    public class ConsoleNotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
    {
        public string Path;
        public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Text);
            await Task.Delay(0);
        }
    }

    public enum MessageType
    {
        // using powers of 2 here so we can bitmask and use Enum.HasFlag
        MessageType1 = 1,
        MessageType2 = 2,
        SomeMailableMessageType = 4, // Don't actually name it this specifically but for demonstration purposes...
        MessageType4 = 8,
        Global = 16
    }

    public class NotificationChannelEngine : INotificationChannelEngine
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<INotificationChannel, MessageType> _notificationChannels;
        public NotificationChannelEngine()
        {
            _notificationChannels = new Dictionary<INotificationChannel, MessageType>();
        }

        public void RegisterNotificationChannel(INotificationChannel channel, MessageType messageType)
        {
            _notificationChannels.Add(channel, messageType);
        }

        public void Process(Message message)
        {
            foreach (var channel in _notificationChannels.Where(channel => message.MessageType == MessageType.Global || channel.Value.HasFlag(message.MessageType)))
                channel.Key.Send(message);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly NotificationChannelEngine NotificationChannel = new NotificationChannelEngine();

        public static void Main()
        {
            //shared variables
            // Common.Log = new Database().GetLogPath();
            // Common.IsDebug = new Database().GetisDebug();
            //registering specific channels

            // register file notification to subscribe to message type 1
            NotificationChannel.RegisterNotificationChannel(new FileNotificationChannel() { Path = "mypath" }, MessageType.MessageType1);

            // register console notification to subscribe to message types 2 and 4
            NotificationChannel.RegisterNotificationChannel(new ConsoleNotificationChannel(), MessageType.MessageType2 | MessageType.MessageType4);

            // register mail notification to subscribe to a mailable type (name this more generically but I want this example to be clear)
            NotificationChannel.RegisterNotificationChannel(new MailNotificationChannel(), MessageType.SomeMailableMessageType);

            new Runner(NotificationChannel).Run(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Wait();
        }
    }


    internal class Runner
    {
        public INotificationChannelEngine NotificationChannelEngine;

        public Runner(INotificationChannelEngine notificationengine)
        {
            NotificationChannelEngine = notificationengine;
        }

        public async Task Run(DateTime date)
        {
            try
            {
                //some operation 1
                // This will send to all channels
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log", MessageType = MessageType.Global });

                //some operation 2
                // This will send only to channels subscribed for MessageType1 (just the file notification)
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log 2", MessageType = MessageType.MessageType1 });

                //some operation 3
                //i would like exclude mail from here
                // This will send to all channels registered for event types other than SomeMailableMessageType (but not excluding them depending on how they are registered)
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log 2", MessageType = MessageType.MessageType1 | MessageType.MessageType2 | MessageType.MessageType4 });

                //now resume mail again
                //some operation 4
                // This will send to all channels again
                NotificationChannelEngine.Process(new Message() { Text = "Some log 2", MessageType = MessageType.Global });

            }
            catch { /* Do something here */ }
        }
    }


    public sealed class Logger
    {
        public static void Log(string msg, string filePath)
        {
            // your original log implementation here
        }
    }
```

The key piece in all of that is as long as you're clever about what message types you create and how you determine which channels should be subscribed to which types, you can have very fine granularity over which channels receive which messages without having unnecessary coupling. You could even modify this to take a message type blacklist so that regardless if channels match one of a message's types they won't be notified as long as one of their subscribed types is blacklisted by the message being passed... but you could find plenty of ways to complicate it or make it more robust for your purposes if the main idea works well enough for you.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide implementation based on my code which you just proposed?

Comment: @Arie I've added an example based on the code you provided. What do you think?

Comment: hmm looks nice, however unless there are still not exact names that Runner doesnt know however still names are required i mean MessageTyp1 etc.. Looks better and will check.

Comment: Yeah, in your example runner needs to know what types of messages it's creating but in actuality that responsibility would go to whatever distributed message creators there are. However, knowing the message type does not increase coupling as long as it doesn't know how that message type is used (i.e. it having to know to use a certain message type to get a certain notifier to respond). You can create soft dependencies if you structure it poorly like I did in this example in order to be explicit about your mail exclusion requirement, but as long as it's configured well it's scalable.

Comment: The knowledge of the links really just has to reside with you as the developer depending on the scheme you set up. After that everything just operates generically.

Comment: but do you think this entire solution would look nice according to OOP approach or there is something than can be changed?

Comment: This is very close to what you'd want to go for when following an OOP approach except for the message creation. I'm assuming you are monitoring various events that you want to be notified of, so I'd put those event monitors into their own classes and have them be responsible for generating their own messages instead of having the runner know how to construct each message. That would leave you with a message bus, various publishers, various subscribers, and a simple system in the middle responsible for hooking that all together in a generic way.

Comment: But in order to know if this works best for you we'd need to fully understand why you want one channel excluded from that one message. Is it based on message type, message source, sequence timing, etc? This solution abstracts out the message type and uses that as a generic discriminator so ideally not even the runner knows what message goes where but there might be an adaptation of this that works better for your scenario while maintaining full separation of concerns depending on how you want to discriminate.

Comment: I think ideally you'd have event watchers constructing messages and posting them to a message bus where the runner would pick them up and publish them to whatever notification channels have subscribed to those message types. You could even modify this structure slightly to have your notification channels register not only with what types of messages they are interested in but also what message types they never want to be notified of even if those messages also match types they are interested in. That would give you very granular control during setup but a very agnostic implementation.